# ngx-spinner not working for synchronous code

Tags: angular

Using [ngx-spinner](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-spinner) for asynchronous operations (service calls, timeouts) is working fine. When its used for synchronous code(for loop) its not showing the spinner.

Created a stackblitz demo with loop and an alert is added to stop execution of code and then spinner hide code is written, but cannot see the spinner.

```
 this.spinner.show();
let i;
for(i=2; i<100; i++) {
  this.numbers.push(i);
}
alert(i);
this.spinner.hide();
```

You can find the code [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-spinner-demo-async?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).

Hack : Adding code inside setTimeout helps in loading of the spinner.

Comment: the spinner is only rendered when the current call stack completes, if you use sync code, the last status for spinner is hide, so it won't get a chance to show at all.

Comment: on top of that there is literally no processing time necessary to count up to 100 in a for loop. the spinner would never be visible to the human eye.

Comment: @jahller, my requirement is to show spinner for synchronous code. say we have very big for loop and we have dom manipulation and if it takes couple of seconds, It should show loader.

Comment: @ABOS Thanks for the answer. So does DOM update for showing spinner happens only after stack clears.

Comment: @PushkalBoganatham, yes, browser updates page during its own paint cycle, which is after that.

Comment: so what solution you get? i also face same issue

Comment: @pal The first comment given by ABOS is the solution.

Comment: @ABOS but my code block is synchronous, and it takes time for rendering. And I need spinner for the same. What changes should I make?

Comment: @SavanGadhiya  Put the code inside setTimeout, it will work. Its a hack.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
async myFunction()
{
 this.spinner.show();
 await showSpinner2();
 this.spinner.hide();
}
showSpinner2()
{
  let i;
  for(i=2; i<100; i++) {
    this.numbers.push(i);
  }
  alert(i);   
}
```

Comment: The above code shows spinner, but doesnt hide it. You can find the code changes in showSpinner3() here (https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-spinner-demo-async-wto2yn).